# Error while installing plugin for redmine

Tags: ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

My redmine version is 
[image]

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                4.1.0.stable
  Ruby version                   2.6.5-p114 (2019-10-01) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  5.2.4.1
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               PostgreSQL
  Mailer queue                   ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter
  Mailer delivery                smtp
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.10.4
  Mercurial                      4.8.2
  Bazaar                         2.8.0
  Git                            2.20.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_image_clipboard_paste  3.3.0
```

I deploy it from docker [container](https://hub.docker.com/_/redmine)

```
$ cat Makefile
.ONESHELL:
docker-deploy:
    mkdir -p ${APP_ROOT}/db/pgdata
    docker network create --driver bridge ${DOCKER_CONTAINER}-net
    docker run -d --name ${DOCKER_CONTAINER}-db -p ${DB_PORT}:5432   \
        --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro     \
        -v ${APP_ROOT}/db/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata     \
        -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata                    \
        -e PGTZ=Europe/Zaporozhye                                    \
        -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT}                              \
        -e POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}                                  \
        --restart='always'                                           \
        --network ${DOCKER_CONTAINER}-net                            \
        postgres:12.2
    docker run -d --name ${DOCKER_CONTAINER} -p ${WW_PORT}:3000      \
        -v ${APP_ROOT}/db/redmine/files:/usr/src/redmine/files       \
        -v ${APP_ROOT}/db/redmine/plugins:/usr/src/redmine/plugins   \
        --link ${DOCKER_CONTAINER}-db:postgres                       \
        -e REDMINE_DB_POSTGRES=${DOCKER_CONTAINER}-db                \
        -e REDMINE_DB_USERNAME=${DB_USER}                            \
        -e REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT}                            \
        --restart='always'                                           \
        --network ${DOCKER_CONTAINER}-net                            \
        redmine:4.1.0
```

When I install [Unread issues](http://rmplus.pro/en/redmine/plugins/unread_issues) plugin, I get error:

```
 NameError: undefined method `store_translations' for module `Redmine::I18n::Backend::Implementation'
```

I am not ruby programist. Does any know how to fix this?

**UPD** 
I follow instruction "How to install the plugin «Unread Issues» in Redmine" from plugin page.

I copy files from `Redmine 4.0 and higher` into `plugins` directory:
[image]

`rgloader` is copied to the root of redmine
[image]

Comment: Did you install the correct version of the plugin? Is it compatible with your redmine version? Did you follow all the instructions provided by the gem? Hard to say anything else with this limited amount of information :)

Comment: @Viktor: question is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redmine support answers that theirs plugin does not support version highier 4.0.6

> Our plugins does not work with redmine 4.1.0, just 4.0.6. We have in progress to update still.

Answer (score 2):

RMPlus team stopped to respond for any messages, I hope they will be back soon :)
As in answer latest version of a_common_libs is encoded for redmine < 4.1, but You can easily find bit older forks in plain ruby. Some of them are already modified for redmine 4.1 but still not perfect:
https://github.com/agrus/a_common_libs/tree/redmine_4.x
https://github.com/karthickmadhiazhagan/a_common_libs

I'm leaving this note here because more and more people are looking for new version and developers are still not available :(